# Undefined Method 'captures' with Postmarkdown ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, markdown

My rails app is not loading up for some reason

```
index.html.haml where line #4 raised:
undefined method `captures' for nil:NilClass
```

my config/routes:

```
 postmarkdown :as => :blog
 root :to => 'posts#index'
```

my  posts/index.html.haml

```
= render 'feed_link'

%section#posts
  - if collection.present?
    = render collection, :summary => true
    = paginate collection
  - else
    No posts found.
```

I am using this gem: https://github.com/ennova/postmarkdown

Comment: Is it collection or @collection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems that one or more of your files in app/posts/ does not conform
>   to the filename format required by Postmarkdown. Please refer to the
>   examples in our readme.

Please check the github project issue:

https://github.com/ennova/postmarkdown/issues/15

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am running into the same issue with heroku though. `rails s` and localhost is all fine and dandy, but once i deploy to heroku the same 'captures' error occurs. even after `git push heroku master` - if you have any idea please let me know! thanks

Comment: Not sure, when are you receiving the error from Heroku? Can I see the log?